# 'static' appears in my url to the next page

Tags: python-3.x, django, url, pagination, django-staticfiles

I've hosted my web app on pythonanywhere.com but i have a problem when trying to route to the next item in a pagination object.

The home page contains a list of contents (blogs)

Down below, i have a pagination. Normally, when i click on the next button, the url should be "https://domain_name/?page=page_num" but instead it turns to "https://domain_name/static/?page=page_num" and it renders a 404 page

The is my static url, root and dirs settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "blog/static/blog"
]
```

```
`{% if is_paginated %}

      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
          <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
      {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
```

[Static url and path on pythonanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTgqW.png)

**blog urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (PostListView, PostDetailView, UserPostListView, 
                    RequestAuthorshipView, PostByCategoryView, like_post, CommentView, CommentUpdateViewView)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name="blog_home"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path("post/<str:username>/posts", UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user_posts"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/comment", CommentView.as_view(), name="add_comment"),
    path("post/comment/<int:pk>/<int:post_id>/edit", CommentUpdateViewView.as_view(), name="edit_comment"),
    path("posts/<str:category>/", PostByCategoryView.as_view(), name="category_posts"),
    path("authorship/request/", RequestAuthorshipView.as_view(), name="request_authorship"),
    path('like/<int:pk>/', like_post, name='like_post'),
]
```

**help_desk.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("blog.urls"), name='blog'),
    path("login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"), name="login"),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="accounts/logout.html"), name="logout"),
    path("password_reset/", 
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset.html"), name="password_reset"),
    path("password_reset_complete/", 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset_complete.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
    path("password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>", 
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset_confirm.html"), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path("password_reset/done", 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset_done.html"), name="password_reset_done"),
    path("password_reset/done", 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="accounts/password_reset_done.html"), name="password_reset_done"),
    path("account/", account_views.account, name="account"),
    path('ticket/new', BookTicketView.as_view(), name='book_ticket'),
    path('tickets/<str:username>/tickets', TicketView.as_view(), name='my_tickets'),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/update', UpdateTicketView.as_view(), name="update_ticket"),
    path('dashboard', DashboardView.as_view(), name="dashboard")
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: what does the code in the template look like for your next button?

Comment: I've just added the code from the template

Comment: Could you add also how you define routing (urls)?

Comment: I have added that too

Comment: does the current url you are on end in '/static'? It would seem to be the only way this would happen.

Comment: Not really. I have used a function view and it worked fine but i don't know why it would'nt work for a clas based view